# autocompletion - How to add phrases as thesaurus synonyms

Tags: autocompletion, thesaurus

I have a thesaurus file which contains synonyms for the word `iterate`. I would like to add an alternative phrase for `iterate` like `loop over` so I added it to the thesaurus. Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Vim displays "loop over" as two entries.

This is from `:help thesaurus`

```
'thesaurus' 'tsr'   string  (default "")
        global or local to buffer |global-local|
        {not in Vi}
List of file names, separated by commas, that are used to lookup words
for thesaurus completion commands |i_CTRL-X_CTRL-T|.

Each line in the file should contain words with similar meaning,
separated by non-keyword characters (white space is preferred).
Maximum line length is 510 bytes.
```

It looks like whitespace is used to separate entries of the thesaurus. Which is weird because, up until this point, I had only been using a comma-separated list for the thesaurus and that worked fine.

Escaping the space character doesn't work unfortunately.

Does anyone know how I can get a phrase as a thesaurus option for a specific word?

Answer (score 1):

To add sentences as thesaurus, you need the `'iskeyword'` option to contain the space character (32 in ascii). Your thesaurus file should then contain spaces only to separate words in a thesaurus sentence and not to separate entries :

```
iterate,loop,loop over
branch,condition
...
```

I found [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/55y53e/allow_spaces_in_thesaurus_entries/) that works well to add `32` to `'iskeyword'` just before launching the popup menu, then removes it after a short time period. The trick is to `set iskeyword+=32` after setting a self-destructing `autocmd` that restores it after 200ms, so you keep your `iskeyword` clean.

Here is an updated version :

```
function! Keyword32()
    let s:saved_iskeyword = &iskeyword
    let s:saved_updatetime = &updatetime
    if &updatetime > 200 | let &updatetime = 200 | endif
    augroup Keyword32
        autocmd CursorHold,CursorHoldI <buffer>
                    \ let &updatetime = s:saved_updatetime |
                    \ let &iskeyword = s:saved_iskeyword |
                    \ autocmd! Keyword32
    augroup END
    set iskeyword+=32
endfunction
inoremap <c-x><c-t> <C-O>:call Keyword32()<CR><c-x><c-t>
```

Note that with this mapping, when you would like to use the `^X` submode, it will take `'timeoutlen'`ms until it shows you the `-- ^X mode (^]^D...)` line. You could map something else if you want. Also make sure you have a reasonable `timeoutlen` in insert mode.

---

Update : since vim 8.0, you can use a timer instead of the `autocmd` :

```
function! Thesaurus32()
    if has('timers') && !empty(&thesaurus)
        call timer_start(200, {_->execute('set iskeyword-=32')})
        set iskeyword+=32
    endif
    return "\<c-x>\<c-t>"
endfunction
inoremap <expr> <c-x><c-t> Thesaurus32()
```